# Template constructor in template class must be defined in the class definition?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

suppose I write a template class with a template constructor, like that.

```
template<typename T>
class X{


    template<typename S>
    X(X<S> x){}
};
```

compiles fine. However, when I try to define the constructor outside of the template declaration, like this:

```
template<typename T>
class X{


    template<typename S>
    X(X<S> x);
};


template<typename T, typename S>
X<T>::X(X<S> y){}
```

I receive the following error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class X<T>’
```

why? Is it not possible to define a template constructor of a template class outside of the class declaration?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two levels of templates, and have to specify them separately.

```
template<typename T>
template<typename S>
X<T>::X(X<S> y){}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename S>
X<T>::X()( X<S> y )
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your class has a single template parameter, and you essentially have a template function inside of it, so you need

```
template<typename T>
template <typename S>
X<T>::X(X<S> y){}
```